# Read Specific line and ignore others using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file like this:

```
input file
yuorvsdsd
dfdsfsd
?dsfsdfsd
sdfsdfs
?dfd
ds
```

I am trying to make it so that it only reads the lines start with `?`. The `readlines` function reads all lines, so I put a condition on it, but I am not satisfied with it, as it's not showing me the accurate results. I want `output` to be:

```
?dsfsdfsd
?dfd
```

Program

```
fp = open("file.txt")
z = fp.readlines
if z=='?':
    print z
fp.close()
```

This is the code which I tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use something like the following:

```
with open("file.txt") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        if line.startswith('?'):
            print line
```

By using a context manager (`with ... as`) the closing of the file will happen automatically after you are done with it.

Comment: Wow... that was uncanny the timing of that!

Answer (score 2):

List comprehensions make this simple:

```
filtered = [line for line in fp.readlines() if line.startswith("?")]
```

Comment: More succinct? yes. More pythonic? Ehhhh.

Comment: You can make it a one-liner by skipping readlines (which is 99% unnecessary anyway): `[line for line in open("file.txt") if line.startswith("?")]`

Answer (score 2):

I think I'd go with a generator expression:

```
(line for line in open('file.txt') if line.startswith('?'))
```

A complete program looks like:

```
lines = (line for line in open('file.txt') if line.startswith('?'))
print ''.join(lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this not work?

```
with open("file.txt") as fin:
    for line in fin:
        if not line.startswith('>'):
            print line
```

Alternatively, could you not just pipe this through `grep` first?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use `line[0]` to get the first character of each line.

```
with open("file.txt") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        if line[0] == '?':
            print line
```

This is possible because String in Python can be indexed. Python's String, like C, starts with the index `0`. `line[0]` will give you a character at index 0, which is the first character.